# URLs separation with bs4 and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a site for a bunch of links and those links are in single HTML `div` tag with `<br />` tag to line break, but when I try to get all URLs from that `div` it just coming in a single string.

I am unable to separate then in `list`. My code is as follows:

**with below code I'm scraping all links:**

```
links = soup.find('div', id='dle-content').find('div', class_='full').find(
            'div', class_='full-news').find('div', class_='quote').text
```

**Following is html from site:**

```
<div class="quote">
<!--QuoteEBegin-->
https://example.com/asd.html
<br>
https://example.net/abc
<br>
https://example.org/v/kjg/
<br>
<br>
<!--QuoteEEnd-->
</div>
```

**Output which I get from above code:**

```
https://example.com/asd.htmlhttps://example.net/abchttps://example.org/v/kjg/
```

**Output which I want:**

```
[
"https://example.com/asd.html",
"https://example.net/abc",
"https://example.org/v/kjg/"
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample = """<div class="quote">
<!--QuoteEBegin-->
https://example.com/asd.html
<br>
https://example.net/abc
<br>
https://example.org/v/kjg/
<br>
<br>
<!--QuoteEEnd-->
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(sample, "html.parser").find_all("div", class_="quote")
print([i.getText().split() for i in soup])
```

Output:

```
[['https://example.com/asd.html', 'https://example.net/abc', 'https://example.org/v/kjg/']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could fix it with a string manipulation:

```
new_output = ' http'.join(output.split('http')).split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the string, and then use list comprehension to bring it together:

```
output = 'https://example.com/asd.htmlhttps://example.net/abchttps://example.org/v/kjg/'
split_output = output.split()
new_output = [x for x in split_output if x != '']
```

**Output:**

```
print(new_output)
['https://example.com/asd.html', 'https://example.net/abc', 'https://example.org/v/kjg/']
```

Comment: Some of them are with http:// only and some are https:// how can I specify it now??

Comment: well you could but in a condition. But actually, might just work the way I edited it above.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve the desired output:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <div class="quote">
    <!--QuoteEBegin-->
    https://example.com/asd.html
    <br>
    https://example.net/abc
    <br>
    https://example.org/v/kjg/
    <br>
    <br>
    <!--QuoteEEnd-->
    </div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print([i.strip() for i in soup.find("div",class_="quote").strings if i!='\n'])
```

Output:

```
['https://example.com/asd.html', 'https://example.net/abc', 'https://example.org/v/kjg/']
```